# Disable automatic movement of a horizontal scrollbar in a tree table structure SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have an issue in which the scrollbar of a tree table item scrolls automatically on clicking any of the column in the table. 
How do I control the movement?
But my research shows that it is Windows behavior.
If it cannot be solved, where exactly should I raise bug for it?
Expecting for replies. Thanks

This is my Tree and when I select any colum(marked in red), the horizontal scrollbar scrolls automatically

[image]

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reform your question. Add more information e.g. code you already tried.

Comment: Can That be solved using SWT?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking. Can you please elaborate and maybe add a screenshot that shows your issue?

Comment: @Roja So it scrolls the column into view? And you don't want that?

Comment: Yes. I don't want that